# How to call a script after every bash command

Tags: bash

Is it possible to call a script in this example named `hey.sh` after every bash command?

For example you type `ls` hit enter and ls runs, then `hey.sh` would run.

You then type `cd ..` *(or any other command)*, cd runs then `hey.sh` would run, and so on.

Comment: This is either an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) or a very odd idea; what are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: alias in bash.rc maybe?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND+="hey.sh;"
```

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>                 If  set,  the  value  is  executed  as a command prior to issuing each primary
>                 prompt.

---

### Note: Environment variables vs shell variables

By default, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is **not** an **environment variable**. It's just a **shell variable**.

Both types of variables are accessed the same way (`"$variable*"`), but *environment variables* are inherited by child processes whereas *shell variables* aren't.

The convention is to capitalize *environment variables* + shell variables that configure your shell (PROMPT_COMMAND does configure your shell), but keep other types of variables lower case.

In *bash*, you can do: `declare -p` to find out whether a variable is exported (=is an environment variable) or not:

```
$ declare -p PATH
declare -x PATH=... #-x means it's exported
$ declare PROMPT_COMMAND
declare -- PROMPT_COMMAND=... #no -x so just a shell variable
```

Comment: @John No. Don't `export` it. Just set it (or append to it, e.g., as shown above).

Comment: Neat, what about after though?

Comment: @moonbutt74 prior to every command == after every command + at the beginning of your bash session

Comment: @PSkocik I gotcha I was just curious if that was already an environmental variable, upon a quick echo command I found out it was.  This does exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @John By default, it's just a shell variable not an environment variable.

Comment: @PSkocik "prior to every command == after every command + at the beginning of your bash session" -- true for strict sequencing but no longer holds when time is considered. If you want something that depends on the time you hit the Enter key that is much harder to do.